# nginx behind reverse proxy 504 Gateway Time-out on form submit

Tags: nginx, haproxy, timeout

I have a problem with nginx. When I use the site directly everything works fine but as soon as I setup a reverse proxy (doesn't matter if its another nginx or haproxy) I get 504 Gateway Time-out when I try to submit forms with content bigger then about 64k. Everything else works as expected with or without proxy

Comment: So nginx alone works but if you add the reverse proxy in front of it, it causes trouble. Yet you think that the problem is with nginx?

Comment: @Oliver Yes. As it doesnt matter which reverse proxy software I use